# If $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=n$, what are the $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $\operatorname{rank(B)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices.

Any hints on how to solve this or where to find the answer are welcome

Comment: **Hint:** There exists a theorem that relates the rank of matrices with the rank of their product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an $n\times n$ matrix $C$ has rank $n$ it is invertible, which means $\mathrm{det}(C)\neq 0$.  If the rank is less than $n$ then $\mathrm{det}(C)=0$.  Since $\mathrm{det}(AB)=\mathrm{det}(A)\mathrm{det}(B)$, we can only have $\mathrm{det}(AB)\neq 0$ if $\mathrm{det}(A)\neq 0$ and $\mathrm{det}(B)\neq 0$, so therefore $A$ and $B$ must have rank $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The rank of a product is always less or equal to the rank of each factor.

Also what is the maximum rank of a $n \times n$ matrix?.

Now you should be able to figure this out